# Google cast stream html files

Tags: html, google-chrome, chromecast

So i am just testing an checking what works and what not with cast. I am trying to stream a html file to the tv. So the code i think is the part i dont get is why the code i have pointed out in yellow does not work as it should. When i cast to my tv i get nothing. There is a chance it does not support html?

> var mediaInfo = new
>   chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo('http://danielchr.com/cast/test.html');
>           mediaInfo.contentType = 'text/html';

This is my code.

```
var session = null;

$( document ).ready(function(){
        var loadCastInterval = setInterval(function(){
                if (chrome.cast.isAvailable) {
                        console.log('Cast has loaded.');
                        clearInterval(loadCastInterval);
                        initializeCastApi();
                } else {
                        console.log('Unavailable');
                }
        }, 1000);
});

function initializeCastApi() {
        var applicationID = chrome.cast.media.DEFAULT_MEDIA_RECEIVER_APP_ID;
        var sessionRequest = new chrome.cast.SessionRequest(applicationID);
        var apiConfig = new chrome.cast.ApiConfig(sessionRequest,
                sessionListener,
                receiverListener);
        chrome.cast.initialize(apiConfig, onInitSuccess, onInitError);
};

function sessionListener(e) {
        session = e;
        console.log('New session');
        if (session.media.length != 0) {
                console.log('Found ' + session.media.length + ' sessions.');
        }
}

function receiverListener(e) {
        if( e === 'available' ) {
                console.log("Chromecast was found on the network.");
        }
        else {
                console.log("There are no Chromecasts available.");
        }
}

function onInitSuccess() {
        console.log("Initialization succeeded");
}

function onInitError() {
        console.log("Initialization failed");
}

$('#castme').click(function(){
        launchApp();
});

function launchApp() {
        console.log("Launching the Chromecast App...");
        chrome.cast.requestSession(onRequestSessionSuccess, onLaunchError);
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
        console.log("Successfully created session: " + e.sessionId);
        session = e;
}

function onLaunchError() {
        console.log("Error connecting to the Chromecast.");
}

function onRequestSessionSuccess(e) {
        console.log("Successfully created session: " + e.sessionId);
        session = e;
        loadMedia();
}

function loadMedia() {
        if (!session) {
                console.log("No session.");
                return;
        }

        var mediaInfo = new
chrome.cast.media.MediaInfo('http://danielchr.com/cast/test.html');
        mediaInfo.contentType = 'text/html';

        var request = new chrome.cast.media.LoadRequest(mediaInfo);
        request.autoplay = true;

        session.loadMedia(request, onLoadSuccess, onLoadError);
}

function onLoadSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully loaded image.');
}

function onLoadError() {
        console.log('Failed to load image.');
}

$('#stop').click(function(){
        stopApp();
});

function stopApp() {
        session.stop(onStopAppSuccess, onStopAppError);
}

function onStopAppSuccess() {
        console.log('Successfully stopped app.');
}

function onStopAppError() {
        console.log('Error stopping app.');
}
```

Answer (score 1):

There are 3 types of Receivers

1. Styled Media Receiver
2. Default Media Receiver
3. Custom Receiver

Google provides default receiver configuration for images and videos but if you want to cast webpage or something custom you have to create your own.

check following links.

- https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/caf_receiver/
- https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/custom_receiver